# How to use Lib like Visual Basic in C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, dll

I'm having a problem which i can really tell you that i need help. I have a lib that have some method that i need. But when I added it as reference, throw this error:

> lib.dll could not be added. Please make sure that the file is
>   accessible, and that it is a valid assambly or COM component.

I can tell you that i dont know in which lenguage is written but thats not the case. I saw in one of the project I worked that someone used the reserve word [Lib](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0bk529yw%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) in Visual Basic with the same Lib and it worked well for him. He could consume the resource  of the lib but the problem is that he developed it in **Visual Basic** and **i dont know anything about Visual Basic**, just **C#**.

This is what he did:

```
Public Function Amethod Lib "theDLLfile" (ByVal s as String) As String...
```

The question is: Could that do that? How to make reference and use its methods? What does the Lib word work and how to use it?

I really need help here.

**LITTLE UPDATE:**

When making reference to DLL, the url can be absolute or relative?

Comment: This is P/Invoke.  Look at the `[DllImport]` attribute.  You will need the full native signature.

Comment: @SLaks it does the same???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use    `[DllImport]`

Example:

```
[DllImport("DllFile.dll", EntryPoint = "dllFunctionName"]
public static extern string functionName (string s);
```

Comment: Method name cannot contain `'`s.

Comment: Replace 'Function' with your Method name. (Dont't write the ') And the EntryPoint is the FunctionName from your dll that you like to use.

Answer (score 3):

That is the older way of doing DllImport in VB.  You also forgot the 'Declare' keyword.  The VB code should have looked like this:

```
Public Declare Function Amethod Lib "theDLLfile" (ByVal s as String) As String
```

The equivalent in C# is:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("theDLLfile")]
public static extern string Amethod(string s);
```

The usual way this would be done in VB now is:

```
<System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("theDLLfile")>
Public Shared Function Amethod(ByVal s As String) As String
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the library is a native library (i.e. unmanaged code, not .NET). You will need to P/Invoke to call into it.

You can find a basic introduction to this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446536.aspx).

You will need some additional information (perhaps from your colleague's VB project) to correctly declare the library functions you want to invoke.